# Progress bar for SheetJS readFile reading large excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, progress-bar, sheetjs

I am working on an Electron/Node.js app to read excel file locally and do some calculations.

The excel file contains 100,000s of rows, each row contains a time stamp and a value at that time.

```
12/17/2019 12:00:00 AM  | 600
```

I could readin the file use [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) package, the code follows

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');

function readExcelandDraw(fileName){
  var workbook = XLSX.readFile(fileName);
  var sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
  var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
  var dataArray = [];
  for(var R = range.s.r; R<=range.e.r; ++R){
      let timecellref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:0, r:R}); 
      let psicellref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:1, r:R});
      if(!sheet[timecellref] && !sheet[psicellref]) continue; // if cell doesn't exist, move on
      let tempTime = sheet[timecellref].v;
      let tempPSI = sheet[psicellref].v;
      dataArray.push({
        Time: getJsDateFromExcel(tempTime),
        psi: tempPSI*6.9
      });
  }
// then plot the dataArray use d3.js
}
```

It took about 25 seconds to read excel file with 600,000 rows.

**Q1**. Is it possible to add a progress bar to indicate the progress of XLSX.readFile?

*Side question:
Is XLSX.readFile Asynchronous function like the fs.readfile() in node.js?*
**No**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The library dev's answer from https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/632:

> As for evented read, the major hurdle is the file format. XLSX uses ZIP files and you have to read in the entire file before you can properly unzip. We will think more about this